# Tflite Model for object detection with swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, tflite, yolov4

I am using tflite model for object detection.
my model has input/output type float32.
could see lots of example in github having models type uint8.

I tried examples from github but input/output type mismatches.
how to set input/output types in code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The Input Output types are set when creating the model in the (usually) python side